# How can i pass a variable with route in laravel form action?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm getting this error...

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
<form action="<?php echo e(url('/update/{{$id); ?>')}} " method="post">
```

if i use like this 
`<form action="{{url('/anyroute/')}} " method="post">`

It works fine.
But if i pass a $id with this it doesn't work.
The Below is the code i'm using..

```
<form action="{{url('/update/{{$id}}')}} " method="post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use concatenation (.)

```
<form action="{{ url('/update/'. $id ) }} " method="post">
</form>
```

Documentation [LINK](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 4):

Use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes), then you'll have more clear and readable code:

In routes:

```
Route::post('/update/{id}', 'SomeController@update')->name('something.update');
```

In view:

```
<form action="{{ route('something.update', ['id' => $id]) }}" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it in laravel 9  like so

```
<form action="{{ route('user.update', [$user->id]) }}" method="post">
</form>

Route::post('/update/{id}', [UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('user.update');
```